# search query joining 3 tables, 1 table has date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

i have 3 tables, the employee table, educational background and job_title,
i need to join the 3 tables and select the latest year the employee is graduated. the result query i need is listed below.

**EMPLOYEE TABLE**

```
|ID | employee_id |   Name             |   
| 1 | 123         | Jewel Brin         | 
| 2 | 554         | Donna Ferry        | 
| 3 | 853         | Ricky David        |
```

**educational background**

```
|ID | employee_id | School/level       | date graduated |
| 1 | 123         | highschool         | 2007           |
| 2 | 123         | college            | 2011           |
| 3 | 554         | college            | 2010           |
| 4 | 554         | masteral           | 2013           |
```

**job title**

```
|ID | employee_id | Job description    |
| 1 | 123         | Free lancer        |
| 2 | 554         | admin assistant    |
| 3 | 853         | Support Admin      |
```

i need to select the latest date info of the employee's educational background

the result would be:

**result query**

```
|ID | employee_id | Name               | Job title       | year_graduated | school_institute |
| 1 | 123         | Jewel Brin         | Free Lancer     |    2011        | college          |
| 2 | 554         | Donna Ferry        | Admin Assistant |    2013        | masteral         |   
| 3 | 853         | Ricky David        | Support Admin   |    Null        |   Null
```

Comment: @vincent [**See Fidde Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb37e/1)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid please look at employee 123 Jewel Brin, the level of employee Jewel Brin is Highschool and it is wrong, the answer should be College. what is wrong with the code ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - please try to look at the error. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Mysql you can try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 e.employee_id,
 e.Name,
 j.Job_description,
 eb.year_graduated,
 eb.level 
FROM
 EMPLOYEE e 
 LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT 
 *,
 MAX(t.date_graduated) year_graduated 
 FROM
 (SELECT * FROM Background ORDER BY date_graduated DESC) t 
 GROUP BY employee_id) eb 
 ON (e.employee_id = eb.employee_id) 
 LEFT JOIN JobTitle j 
 ON (e.employee_id = j.employee_id)
```

### [**See Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb37e/11)

Comment: please look at employee 123 Jewel Brin, the level of employee Jewel Brin is Highschool and it is wrong, the answer should be College. what is wrong with the code ?

Comment: @Vincent see my updated answer with [**updated fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb37e/11)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to mention, this is MySQL :)

```
SELECT e.employee_id, Name, `Job description` AS `Job title`, year_graduated, school_institute
FROM `employee` e
INNER JOIN job_title j ON j.employee_id = e.employee_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, `School/level` AS school_institute, employee_id, `date graduated` AS year_graduated FROM `educational background` b
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ID, MAX(`date graduated`) AS max_date FROM `educational background` GROUP BY employee_id
        ) b2
    ON b2.max_date = b.year_graduated AND b2.ID = b.ID
    ) bb ON bb.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

Comment: i edited my question. i also need to have results also of the people who does not have educational background. thanks

Comment: i edited my question, please refer to the result query below. thanks !

Comment: @Vincent Don't you get that with my query?

Comment: @-NewInTheBusiness i edited my qeustion. i have encountered new problems.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server :-

```
Select *
from 
(
 Select e.ID,e.employee_ID,e.Name,
 b.Level,j.[Job description],
 rn = row_number() 
 over (partition by e.Employee_ID order by [date graduated] desc)
 From Employee e
 left join Background b
 on e.Employee_ID = b.Employee_ID
 left join Jobtitle j
 on j.Employee_ID = b.Employee_ID
 )a
 where a.rn=1
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7fc18/26)

Comment: i edited my question. please refer to this. thanks you !

Comment: Check the updated answer. You need all the employees irrespective whether they have any background or not. So in that case u need to replace `inner join` with `Left join`

Comment: `Row_number`  returns a sequential number group by Employee ID. So for ex if there are 3 employees having ID=3, then they will be numbered sequentially based on the `graduated dete`. `rn` is an alias

Comment: The above query works in sql server. I'm not sure abou the syntax in `Mysql`

Comment: the query is not working in Mysql. is there other way ?